# Azure Ad B2C Sign in with apple in the native way

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal, sign-in-with-apple

I would love to know if there's a possibility to implement "Sign in with Apple" button without opening a web page using Swift on iOS.

Are we able to, somehow, implement the authorization without opening the web page? It would be great that user gets the system prompt right after tapping "Sign in with Apple" button (as it was designed by Apple) without opening any page which might look kinda shady.

I feel like I've taken a look everywhere but most of the questions either don't have any answer or are old and possibly irrelevant at the moment.

I followed sample [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-mobile-apple-swift-objc), configured everything on Apple side, in Azure portal and currently, when I try to authorize, the app opens webview with apple login which triggers popup shown below, user gets authorized, gets a record within Azure AD B2C users and is redirected back to the app. But that's not what we want to as it's awful UX.
[Sign in with Apple native prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucVJK.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft does not provide authentication API endpoints for any of its products (e.g. Azure AD, ADFS) so No.

Technically, you could use [ROPC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-ropc-policy?tabs=app-reg-ga&pivots=b2c-user-flow) but that's being deprecated and it's not secure.

Comment: ROPC would require the App to get the password, correct?
If that's possible I wonder if it is somehow possible to get a session and use prompt=none + login_hint in a webrequest.